# A meshabarach prior to going on aliyah

Tags: tefilla, torah-service, aliya-laaretz

My family and I will be making Aliyah in a couple of weeks. Is there a customary meshabarach for a person who is about to make Aliyah?

Comment: Mazel Tov! We wish you much success on your journey! ושבו בנים לגבולם

Comment: Congratulations and much good luck!

Comment: Surely the prayer for something new is suitable and applicable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This [Mi Shebeirach](http://www.biu.ac.il/JH/Parasha/tazria/pare.pdf) was authored in 1948 in Morocco for those that were making Aliya.

> מי שבירך אבותינו הקדושים והטהורים אברהם יצחק ויעקב משה ואהרן דוד ושלמה
>   הוא יברך וישמור וינצור כל אחינו בני ישראל אנשים ונשים וטף זקנים
>   וצעירים ההולכים בים וביבשה ובאוירון לעלות לארץ אבותינו. מלך מלכי
>   המלכים ברחמיו ישמרם ויחיים, ומכל צרה וניזק(!) יצילם. מלך מלכי המלכים
>   ברחמיו יבטל מעליהם ומעלינו כל גזירות קשות ורעות, ויגזור עליהם ועלינו
>   גזירות טובות, ויגיעם למחוז חפצם לשלום ויאריכו ימים על אדמת הקודש. מלך
>   מלכי המלכים ברחמיו יקרב גאולתינו ועלייתנו לארצנו ונבלה שם ימינו בטוב
>   ובחירות על התורה ועל העבודה. ובא לציון גואל וכן יהי רצון ונאמר אמן.